# Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) does not show unreachable objects

Tags: mat

I have used both standalone EMA (1.5.0) and eclipse plugin (in eclipse 4.5) to analyze my heap dump.

I want to see any unreachable objects info, I have tried to enable keep_unreachable_objects option in my preference and command line option of -keep_unreachable_objects as mentioned [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#MAT_Does_Not_Show_the_Complete_Heap).

But I still don't have Java Basics --> Unreachable Objects Histogram.

Is this because there in no unreachable objects in my heap dump? I thought once I enabled, at least I should see the option in "Java Basics" drop down list.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I found it here (Window -> Preferences -> Memory Analyzer)
http://joxi.ru/D2PQw3Vhd3dxeA

Answer (score 3):

Disable MAT --> Preferences --> Memory Analyzer --> Keep Unreachable objects.

Then Java Basics --> Unreachable Objects Histogram should start showing.

It seems counter intuitive, but I guess when the preference is enabled, MAT does not distinguish between referenced and unreachable objects and therefore, the Unreachable Objects Histogram is not available in Java Basics.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the document from: https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/welcome.html

As @justAnotherGuy said, you should disable Keep Unreachable objects, then you will see Unreachable Objects Histogram in Java Basics.
And if you parse dump before while Keep Unreachable objects enable , you should

1. Close the snapshot
2. Select the heap dump using Window > Heap Dump History right-click, Delete Index Files
3. Disable 'Keep unreachable objects' using Window > Preferences > Memory Analyzer
   then reparse the dump, you will see Unreachable Objects Histogram in Java Basics.

Also, if you Keep Unreachable objects enable, you can also see the unreachable objects:

1. Select the Java Basics > GC Roots query.
2. Select the 'Unreachable Objects' row.
3. Run the 'Show Retained Set' query on that row.